# the method StringBuilder.append() , has changed the result of String.intern()

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

```
String s1 = new StringBuilder("dsada").append("dfgdfgd").toString();
String s3 = new StringBuilder("aaaa").toString();

System.out.println(s1.intern() == s1);  //true
System.out.println(s3.intern() == s3);  //false
```

the s1 and s3 finally invoke StringBuilder.toString,
the method toString() contrust a new String(),and then invoke the String.intern(),the result is different，it confused me a lot.

```
  @Override
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: `"aaaa"` is a string literal in your code, so it's already in the interned pool. `"dsadadfgdfgd"` is not a string literal in your code, so it's added to the interned pool when you call `intern()`.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern():

> If the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.

`"aaaa"` is a string literal in your code, so it's already in the interned pool. When you call `intern()` on a string with value `"aaaa"`, it returns the existing string object that it retrieved from the pool. That's not the same object as `s3`.

`"dsadadfgdfgd"` is not a string literal in your code, so when you call `intern()`, it adds that string object to the pool, and then returns it, the same object.

Comment: Do note that string literals that can be statically computed like "a" + "b" still get interned as "ab" on modern compilers

Comment: thx, the result s3.intern() == s3  i understand.but  s1.intern() == s1 i do not understand.the s3 is a stringObject

Comment: @concurrentScott `s1.intern()` adds the string object `s1` to the interned pool, and then returns that same string object.

Comment: oh i read the note of intern(), thx